# Call c function from multiple c++ QThreads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, qt, stack

I want to thread processing data by a c-code function with QThread. For that I built an interface that passes the function pointer and a pointer to a section of the data to each thread.

Example:
The data are 4 floats. The function is supposed to multiply the first float with the second one and the third with the fourth.
Now I create two QThreads in c++ and pass the functions pointer as well as a pointer to the first and second element to the first QThread. Then I pass the functions pointer as well as a pointer to the third and fourth element to the second QThread.

For my system with 24 logical cores and 24 different created threads I expect to get up to nearly 24 times the performance but I only get a 20% performance boost.

My theory is that the different threads try to access the same address for the function and slow each other down. Is that correct? How can I create multiple copies of that function for each thread?

I tried to break down some pseudocode. Please don't kill me I obviously have no real programming background:

### c-File that contains the function to be threaded

```c
float* data;
int thread;

setFunctionInterface(&functionToThread, data, thread);

void functionToThread(float* data, int thread){
   someIPPFunction(data[thread])
}
```

### c to c++ interface file

```c
void setFunctionInterface(void (*func)(float* data, int thread), data, thread){
   setFunction(func, data, thread);
}
```

### c++ thread manager

```c
void setFunction(func, data, thread){
   threadManager->getThread(thread)->threadSetFunction(func, data, thread);
}

void QThread::threadSetFunction(func, data, thread){

}


void QThread::run(){
   while(true)
   {
      if(someMutexThatChecksIfJobIsToBeExecuted()){
         (*func)(data, iThread);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: why you need to make your code slow? Based on description what your function does, use of any threads will be harmful for performance and code maintainability. Please provide actual code you need parallelize, explain why you think multiple threads is a good solution.

Comment: 'Then I pass the functions pointer as well as a pointer to the third and fourth element to the second QThread.' nooooooooo:(   Divide all your data up into 24 large chunks, not loads of small chunks!

Comment: There are many issues that could lead to your problems, including (but not limited to) cahcing, data or I/O or CPU contention, inter-thread synchronization, and more.

Comment: @MarekR the code is near irrelevant, only the data matters.  Large chunks of data, not sharing cache lines with each other, are ideal for threading off.

Comment: Don't describe what you are doing, show your code instead and then point out what is not working, or what is not clear.

Comment: @MartinJames code matters to see what is his actual problem. For me this question smells like XY problem.

Comment: I just added some pseudocode, does it help describe the problem? @MarekR I am doing many elementwise multiplications on two for example [2048 x X] matrices. If using single thread my system is too slow. Since I have 24 logical cores available, I was hoping I could somehow split up the matrix and perform the operations in parallel. Since it is dynamically allocated memory the data should be in the heap which is - I believe - shared by threads. Isn't it?